# In a processing sketch, how I can reduce overall size for smaller screen?

Tags: scaling, processing-ide

I have a Processing sketch that has a `size(500,800)`, and I want to show it, for a presentation, on a laptop that appears to allow a maximum y dimension of only 700. Please, is there an easy way to reduce the size? The screen is pretty full of stuff that has all its sizes in pixels, so what I need is a fractional reduction all over: simply reducing the `size();` won't work.

I put a `scale(7/8.0);` in the sketch, trying it before and after the `size(500,800)` and it made no difference.

---

I have solved the immediate problem by rearranging the layout so it all fits within the available space, but I would still be interested to know if re-scaling the sketch output is possible.

Comment: What is a "Processing sketch"? :/

Comment: Processing is a silly name for a brilliant programming language, more than that: a complete system. See processing.org on the 'net. It was originally intended for designers and artists, hence the term "sketch" for what is usually called a "program". I use it for animations for presentations.